# Google Maps API (Google Directions) not working for particular location

Tags: google-maps

While I m trying to draw a route for multi locations using google Map API, the route not available for some locations so the google maps not returning the map. I got the same result while trying by using the lattitude and longitude. One such location is orchha in uttarpradesh India to Delhi.

Answer (score 1):

Driving directions is not yet officially supported in India. See [this spreadsheet](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html) of supported features by country, so you might expect some inconsistencies.

Despite that, some directions requests work in India, for example most individual towns in Uttar Pradesh work. Perhaps the problem is that the geocoded point for Uttar Pradesh happens to be at a very blank area of farmland with no roads nearby. There's a limit to how far from a road a location can be for GDirections to work.